# Using fopen and fwrite with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, fopen

I'm attempting to check for file existence with Zend Framework and, if the file doesn't exist, have it be created.  Here's the code being used:

```
$filename = "/assessmentsFile/rubrics/$rubricID.php";
$somecontent = "test";

if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')) {
    echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

// Write $somecontent to our opened file.
if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === false) {
   echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
   exit;
}
```

However, I assume due to Zend's way of handling file structure, if a file doesn't exist it just spits out:

> Warning: fopen(/assessmentsFile/rubrics/1.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Because the fopen function isn't working, fwrite is unable to write the file.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I through Zend was included in all PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the issue is with the path to `$filename`.

You have

```
$filename = "/assessmentsFile/rubrics/$rubricID.php";
```

which tries to create a file in the root of the server in a directory called `assessmentsFile`.

Most likely you need to be using:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assessmentsFile/rubrics/$rubricID.php";
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should do the trick if the `assessmentsFile` folder is in your web root.  Otherwise there are other variables you can use to get a fully qualified path, or you can simply hard-code the path:

```
$filename = "/home/yoursite/public_html/assessmentsFile/rubrics/$rubricID.php";
```

Comment: Right on. Document Root was the issue. Thanks, drew010!

Comment: I thought that the absolute path was intended... As long as that folder exists (of course in the system root and not in the document root) and it's writable, it should work with it too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function `file_exists` that tells you if the file exists, and with `is_file` you can check it's a file (and not a directory for example).

(Another way is to suppress warnings by putting an @ before the function call (e.g. `$handle=@fopen(...)`, but it's better to check for file existence)

Try this:

```
if(is_file($filename)){ // exists
  $handle=fopen($filename,"w+");
}else{
  $handle=fopen($filename,"w"); // create it
}
// ...
```

Comment: The issue is, due to the fact that fopen is not working, the fwrite function isn't either.

Comment: If file doesn't exists, open it with mode "w" (not "w+"), but beware that if it already existed it is truncated. Check my edited answer...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even with just w, I still get the error `Cannot open file (/assessmentsFile/rubrics/1.php)`, and no file is created.

Comment: Try touching the file before opening it: `touch($filename)`. Another thing is: the file should be created, but the directory doesn't. Does /assessmentsFile/rubrics/ exist?

Comment: Interesting. With touch, I'm seeing this error: `Unable to create file /assessmentsFile/rubrics/1.php because No such file or directory in (myController.php)`.  Is it possible the controller is preventing it from reaching outside of the controller?

EDIT: Just realized that it is spitting this error for fopen too...I can't figure out why it would be looking for the file inside the controller file?

Comment: It may be that, or it may be a permission issue. Try checking both.

Comment: Looks like it was an issue with the path not being the document root! Thanks for the help.